# Ionic - How to create location based login

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, ionic-v1

I'm try to create a location based login app using ionic version 1.
Purpose is to user can submit there attendance (arrival and departure) when they are on office area through app.
The back end stuffs should be on PHP/MySQL for API.

**App features** -

- App will ask user to turn on GPS
- Without GPS Turn on user can't access app
- When user submit a attendance app will send user current location to api.
- A push notification will trigger when user arrive  nearest location of office (with in 100 meters) if GPS on

Here question is -

- How to force user to turn on GPS when open app?
- How to  push notification when users comes to nearest area of office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the `cordova-diagnostic-plugin` to check if the user has given GPS permissions. If he did not, you can just not give him access to the app and tell him he needs to activate it.
2. You can use the `cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation` to set up a geofence around certain points and then send a push notification once the user enters.

Comment: Is there any way to open location setting while promting to turn on GPS?

Comment: You can also do that with the diagnostic plugin